# React + Redux subscribe to action outside of mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the `mapStateToProps` workflow down, but what if I want to respond to actions in a way that doesn't fit well into the state => props paradigm? For instance:

```
this.props.dispatch(saveArticle(...))
// on successful save, redirect to article page
```

If I'm just using regular old XHRs rather than actions, it would look something like this:

```
saveArticle(...).then(article => this.router.push(`/articles/${article.id}`))
```

It's not clear how this would fit in with the standard React/Redux workflow; I've seen people suggest that the `saveArticle()` action creator could fire off the router change, but I want to keep those separate; I should be able to save an article without being forced to redirect.

A workaround could be to do it *in* `mapStateToProps`; have the action set a flag or something, like `articleWasSaved`, and have the component that does the saving look for that prop and redirect if it sees it, but that seems really ugly, especially if multiple things are looking for that update, since it would likely require the component(s) to clear the flag.

Is there a simple/standard solution I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with having the `saveAction` creator change the route.  It would be especially easy with `redux-thunk`.  Your action creator can make the API call, and if it's successful, automatically redirect.  If it fails, you can handle it as you see fit, which may be setting a flag in your state which the component can respond to and update the UI.

Comment: I suppose I could have two separate action creators, one that just does the save and another that does save-and-redirect, and have them use the same action type, that way other code could use the non-redirecting action creator.

Comment: But, IMO, you should be delegating the responsability of acting after an action to the component, while we prefer the component  being lead by the redux state. I mean, the state should indicate if the redirect should be done or not, not the component by itself. IMO

Comment: @TurnerHayes Or just use a single action creator and pass it a `boolean` as a parameter to let it know whether or not it should redirect.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca I'm curious why you feel that is the case; it seems like redirecting is somewhat of a UI detail; that is, should the state be concerned with where it is right now, path-wise? I guess `react-router-redux` does that, but otherwise I wouldn't necessarily consider "current path" to be a state member.

Answer (score 2):

**Redux-thunk** allows you to dispatch functions as actions. It is ideally to dispatch async operations.

Here I've created an example I think It will be useful for you:

### actions.js

```js
export const tryingAsyncAction = () => {
  return {
    type: 'TRYING_ASYNC_ACTION'
  }
}

export const actionCompleted = () => {
  return {
    type: 'ACTION_COMPLETED'
  }
}

export const errorAsyncAction = (error) => {
  return {
    type: 'ERROR_ASYNC_ACTION',
    error
  }
}

export function someAsynAction() {
  return dispatch => {
      dispatch(tryingAsyncAction())
      ApiService.callToAsyncApi(...)
        .then(() => {
          dispatch(actionCompleted())
        }, (cause) => {
          dispatch(errorAsyncAction(cause))
        })
  }
}
```

### reducer.js

```js
const initialState = {
  tryingAction: false,
  actionCompleted: false,
  error: null,
  shouldRedirect: false,
  redirectUrl: null
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TRYING_ASYNC_ACTION':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        tryingAction: true
      })
    case 'ACTION_COMPLETED':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        tryingAction: false,
        actionCompleted: true,
        shouldRedirect: true,
        redirectUrl: 'someUrl'
      })
    case 'ERROR_ASYNC_ACTION':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        tryingAction: false,
        actionCompleted: false,
        error: action.error
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

### Your createStore file

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk' //npm install --save redux-thunk
//Other imports...

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware
  )
)
```

### YourComponent.js

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.shouldRedirect && nextProps.redirectUrl)
    this.router.push(`/articles/${article.id}`)
}
```

Let me know if there is something you dont understand. I will try to clarify

Comment: Right, but as I mentioned above, I wanted to avoid having the redirection logic in the state, since it would require handling that logic somewhere; for example, let's say it does the redirect in `componentWillReceiveProps`. At the point the push is done, the state will still have `shouldRedirect` and `redirectUrl`. That could get confusing.

Comment: One of the concepts behind Redux is that an app is a representation of the state, **single source of truth**, and every action taken in the app is based on the state, so following this path, given a particular state we will know how the app looks like. IMO, of course, in your case you have a behavior that is not represented by the state. Even in your case, how would you know if you had arrived to the rederect route through that action or directly? I hope to be clear enough. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `react-thunk` in this case.

actions/index.js

```
export function saveArticle(data) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => (
    api.post(data).then(response => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_ARTICLE', payload: response })
      return response;
    })
  )
}
```

reducer/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'; 

const initialState = { 
  list: [],
  current: null,
  shouldRedirect: false, 
  redirectTo: null
};

export function articles(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SAVE_ARTICLE': 
      return {
        shouldRedirect: true,
        redirectTo: '/some/url',
        current: action.payload,
        list: [...state.list, action.payload]
      };
    default: return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({ articles });
```

store/index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

component/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as Actions from 'actions/index';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  _handleSubmit = () => {
    // get form values somehow...
    // const values = getFormValues();

   this.props.saveArticle(values).then(response => {
     // you can handle you redirect here as well,
     // since saveArticle is returning a promise
   });
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // you can handle the redirection here listening to changes
    // on shouldRedirect and redirectTo that will be triggered
    // when the action 'SAVE_ARTICLE' is dispatched
    if(nextProps.shouldRedirect && nextProps.redirectTo) {
      this.routes.push(nextProps.redirectTo);
    }
  }

  render() {
    // just an example
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
        { /* ... other elements here */ }
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({ 
    articles: state.articles.list,
    article: state.articles.current,
    redirectTo: state.articles.redirectTo,
    shouldRedirect: state.articles.shouldRedirect
  }), 
  Actions
)(MyComponent);
```

PS: I'm using some babel syntax sugar here, so make sure you're the following presets are set in your `.babelrc`.

- `es2015`
- `stage-2`
- `stage-0`
- `react`

Comment: That seems to be mixing state paradigms though; we use Redux by dispatching an action, but then ignore it in the component and use a returned Promise. It's doable, sure, but I think it would be preferable to stick to one state mechanism.